# math.cos(x) not returning correct value?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I just started using python, and am having difficulty with a very basic program. I want to calculate the cosine of -20 degrees. It is my understanding that the default value is in radians, so this is the following code i tried:

```
import math 


print math.cos(math.degrees(-20))
```

This outputs (-.7208...), where the answer is actually (.9397...). I'm sure this has a pretty basic solution but I've tried so many different things and it will not output the correct results. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `math.degrees(-20)` is not -20 degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#angular-conversion):

> **`math.degrees(x)`**
>
> Convert angle *x* from radians to degrees.

That means you are attempting to convert -20 radians to degrees which isn't desired.

Also per the documentation:

> **`math.cos(x)`**
>
> Return the cosine of `x` radians.

This means `math.cos` finds the cosine of the passed argument in *radians*, not degrees. That means your code currently changes -20 radians to degrees, then finds the cosine of that as if it were radians... you can see why that's a problem.

You need to convert -20 degrees to radians, and then find the cosine. Use [`math.radians`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#angular-conversion):

```
math.cos(math.radians(-20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to input in radians, so do

```
math.cos(math.radians(-20))
```

math.radians(-20) converts -20 degrees to radians.

Answer (score 0):

`math.degrees` takes a number of radians and *produces* a number of degrees. You need the opposite conversion - you have a number of degrees, and you need to produce a number of radians you can pass to `math.cos`. You need `math.radians`:

```
math.cos(math.radians(-20))
```